# How to pass DAG run date to the tasks?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm new with airflow and trying to figure out how to pass the DAG run date to each task, I have this in my DAG:

```
tzinfo=tz.gettz('America/Los_Angeles')
dag_run_date = datetime.now(_tzinfo)

dag = DAG(
    'myDag', 
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval = None,
    params = {
        "runDateTimeTz" : dag_run_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
    }
)
```

Then I try to pass the runDateTimeTz parameter to each of my tasks, something like this..

```
task1 = GKEPodOperator(
    image='gcr.io/myJar:1.0.1.45',           
    cmds=['java'],
    arguments=["-jar","myJar.jar", {{params.runDateTimeTz}}"],
    dag=dag)

task2 = GKEPodOperator(
    image='gcr.io/myJar2:1.0.1.45',           
    cmds=['java'],
    arguments=["-jar","myJar2.jar", {{params.runDateTimeTz}}"],
    dag=dag)
```

My tasks are executed correctly but I was expecting all of them to receive the same run date in params.runDateTimeTz, but It didn't happen, for example task1 gets `params.runDateTimeTz=2020-04-16T07:42:47.412716-07:00` and task2 gets `params.runDateTimeTz= 2020-04-16T07:43:29.913289-07:00`

I suppose this behavior is related to the way airflow fills the `params` for the DAG, looks like params.runDateTimeTz is gotten only when the task starts to run, but I want to get it before and send it to each task as an argument expecting all the task to get the same value.

Can someone assist me on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `execution_date` or `ds` from Airflow Macros:

Details: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref#default-variables

```py
task1 = GKEPodOperator(
    image='gcr.io/myJar:1.0.1.45',           
    cmds=['java'],
    arguments=["-jar","myJar.jar", "{{ ds }}"],
    dag=dag)

task2 = GKEPodOperator(
    image='gcr.io/myJar2:1.0.1.45',           
    cmds=['java'],
    arguments=["-jar","myJar2.jar", "{{ ds }}"],
    dag=dag)
```

If you need a timestamp you can use `{{ ts }}`

Comment: I'm not sure if the execution_date is what I need here. According to [airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#execution-date)  _The execution_date is the logical date and time which the DAG Run_ I want to the actual run date. It's not clear for me what the logical date means here.

Comment: execution_date is the actual date when the Dag runs.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to change the default time zone of the execution_date before sending it to the tasks? I don’t want to sent it with the default UTC.